# Get Bokeh dropdown value without interaction

Tags: bokeh

Below is the code for a small working example of a Bokeh dashboard.

When you make a selection in the first dropdown menu, the second one is updated dynamically and the chart is updated with a new source. This works for options A1/A2 because the data arrays are the same length.

Once you select option B1 in the first dropdown, the second dropdown changes to B2.

But the source update doesn't happen because you cant get the `Yselector.value`.

How can you retrieve the `Yselector.value` without using Bokeh's `on_change` method and pass it to a function like `source_selector`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs, Select
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, Spacer
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, show

#Plotting points on initial chart.
df_AB = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(500, 2)), columns=list('XY'), index=[str(i) for i in range(1,500+1)])
pointchart=figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=700, tools=['lasso_select','box_select','wheel_zoom'],title="Point scatter")
pointchart_source= ColumnDataSource(df_AB[["X","Y"]])
pointchart.circle("X","Y",source=pointchart_source)

#Dropdown X
selectoroptions=['','Series A1', 'Series A2','Series B1','Series B2']
Xselector = Select(title="Dropdown X:", value="", options=selectoroptions)

#Dropdown Y
selectoroptions=['','Series A1', 'Series A2','Series B1','Series B2']
Yselector = Select(title="Dropdown Y:", value="", options=selectoroptions)


#Will list multiple sources to feed the chart based on dropdown selection.
def source_selector(selection):
    if selection=='Series A1':
        newvalues= pd.Series(list(np.random.randint(100, size=500)),name="")
    elif selection=='Series A2': 
        newvalues= pd.Series(list(np.random.randint(200, size=500)),name="")
    elif selection=='Series B1': 
        newvalues= pd.Series(list(np.random.randint(20, size=20)),name="")    
    elif selection=='Series B2': 
        newvalues= pd.Series(list(np.random.randint(10, size=20)),name="")    
    return newvalues


#Once dropdown X seelction is made, the options of dropdown Y will dynamically change. 
#Data used for X axis is updated.
def X_switch_selection_and_source(attr, old, new):
    if new == '':
        pointchart_source.data = ColumnDataSource(df_AB[["X","Y"]]).data

    #Other dropdown changed dynamically
    elif new=='Series A1':
        Yselector.options=['Series A2'] 

    elif new=='Series A2':
        Yselector.options=['Series A1']

    elif new=='Series B1':
        Yselector.options=['Series B2']

    elif new=='Series B2':
        Yselector.options=['Series B1']  


    #Updating source based on this dropdown's selection/ X values. 
    new_x_values=source_selector(new)

    #Issue is right here. This line will only work if y is the same length as new x.
    new_y_values=list(pointchart_source.data["Y"])

    #If the lenghths are different I want to update the source for y by getting the y dropdown value. 
    if len(new_x_values)!= len(new_y_values):
        new_y_values=source_selector(Yselector.value) # Does not get the dynamically changed value in the Y dropdown.

    sourcedf=pd.DataFrame({"X":new_x_values,"Y":new_y_values})
    pointchart_source.data=  ColumnDataSource(sourcedf).data


Xselector.on_change("value", X_switch_selection_and_source)

#Show
layout=row(column(Xselector,Yselector, Spacer(width=400, height=500)),pointchart)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
!powershell -command {'bokeh serve --show Bokeh_dropdown_helped_v2.ipynb'}
```

My goal is for the user to be able to make selections from the dropdowns and for the other dropdown to show only the appropriate selections based on the first selection.

The data used for the axis' will be updated based on the selections.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Select widget values instead of its options. If you change the options, you must make sure that its value is one of the options.

```
elif new=='Series A1':
    Yselector.value='Series A2' 

elif new=='Series A2':
    Yselector.value='Series A1'

elif new=='Series B1':
    Yselector.value='Series B2'

elif new=='Series B2':
    Yselector.value='Series B1'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I can't set the value there because I will most likely have many options available for the `Yselector` for the user to choose. I think that if I want to update the data source based on the selection in two of the dropdowns, it has to be triggered by something other than clicking a new selection in the dropdown (because you can't change both dropdowns at the same time). Is there any way to check which value is currently there like `new_y_values=source_selector(Yselector.value)` ?

Comment: @Kdog as I said in the answer, if you change the options, you must make sure that the value is one of the options.

Comment: By 'will most likely have many options' I meant `Yselector.options=['Series B1','Some other option', 'Another option']`. The callback where this happens cannot set the `value`- the user will have to choose the option from the list. So something needs to happen to see what they picked for the from the `Yselector` from newly set options. Am I misunderstanding your solution? Thanks

Comment: @Kdof Yselector.value always works, it's just that in your example, you never changed the Yselector value from an empty string, so it stays an empty string. So your comment in the code is wrong. You are getting the Yselector value dynamically, it's just taht you never changed it

Comment: Rookie mistake, I'm sitting there looking at a populated field that has no set value. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Kdog you can also tell it works if you add a print statement for Yselector.value, and change the Y dropdown value first before changing X, then it will always have that first chosen value.